# Zend Server CE installation

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-server-ce, zend-rest

I've so far been unable to find a working answer for this... And, let me say, I'm brand new to Zend/MVC.

I've installed Zend Server CE on CentOS, running Apache. I'm able to use the Zend GUI interface (with the options like `"Monitor`, `Applications`, `Server Setup`, etc.). PHP is running and executing fine.

All is ok, except when I try to instantiate any Zend Custom Classes. For instance when I try to create a `Zend_Rest_Controller` class, I receive the following message:

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Rest_Controller' not found in /mnt/hgfs/API/index.php on line 15

This stays the same for any class I try. I read things about altering the `php.ini` file, or including the Zend library in the `index.php` page, but nothing has helped so far.

My question is: **What steps in addition to installing Zend do I need to do to let me use the Zend classes?**

Sorry if this is an ignorant question, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: Typically these types of errors are encountered when a non standard MVC configuration is attempted and the autoloader is not configured correctly. The information provided so far is insufficient to diagnose the problem. Look at the [quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.html) for an idea of how the framework is used for mvc. the [coding standard](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.html) may also prove helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different products of [Zend](http://zend.com/), which I think you are confusing. There is [Zend Server CE](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/) (which you just installed). And there is the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/). As far as I know, Zend Server CE is distributing the Zend Framework with it, but it probably distributes version 2. And, looking at the name of the class you are referring to, that is a class from version 1 of the Zend Framework. Since version 2, the Zend Framework uses namespaces, and thus the class `Zend_Rest_Controller` does no longer exist. If you want to use version 1 Zend Framework, you will have to install that seperately.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll do some more research, but looking at the server information page it lists:


Zend Server Community Edition: v 5.6.0
Zend Framework: v1.12.0

Comment: 1)when i install ZendServer CE on my machine(windows),its up and running on  http://localhost:10081/ZendServer,pls try it with your config                                                                 2)you may need to include Zend library's path into php.ini probably